Telegram API sendMessage and exportChatInviteLink return chat not found
Using the Telegram API, sendMessage and exportChatInviteLink return "chat not found".
Here is the code for invite:
string token = ...
string destId = "Existing Chat id I found from Bot raw in the destination telegram";
string urlString = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/exportChatInviteLink?chat_id={destId}";

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, urlString);

HttpResponseMessage response = null;

try
{
    response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ }

TelegramModel result = null;
// if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
// {
    result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TelegramModel>();
// }
return result;// result;    

How to make this work?
